# Are int a = 5 and int a(5) equivalent in C++?

Tags: c++

Both `int a = 5` and `int a(5)` yield the same output when displayed on stdout. Also `int* b = new int` and `int* b(new int)` seem to be the same. Are those just two different ways to initialize a variable and declare a pointer or is there a bigger picture? Frankly I had no idea you could initialize a primitive data type with no assignment operator.

Comment: Yes they are the same. There is no assignment operator in `int a = 5;`.  The `=` symbol is part of the syntax for initialization.

Comment: in c++11 `int a{5};` will also work.

Comment: My answer was not accepted by the community, so I deleted it, but I think someone should post a comprehensive answer regarding differences between primitives and classes, and when the distinction is important.

Comment: I thought `=` is the assignment operator

Comment: Just a comment on "a trivial way to initialize a primitive data type with no assignment operator": `int foo;`

Comment: @agg3l That doesn't initialise `foo`. It only declares the variable. It's value is _undefined_; you need to ***explicitly initialise*** it to ensure it has a predictable value.

Comment: @CraigYoung Huh, yep. Agreed. let it be `static int foo;` (or `extern int foo;` o_O) then. Please do not be too strict about my comments, hadn't had reread cpp spec for years, as well as not using it on regular basis for a while

Comment: @user6646922 - `=` is the assignment operator, when used within an expression (for example, an expression statement like `a = 5;`).    It is also an element of of syntax for initialisation, when used in a variable definition (say `int a = 5;`).   Although there is similarity of effect, the assignment operation changes the value of `a`, and the variable definition causes `a` to magically spring into existence with the value `5`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they're the same.

On the other hand, for a class type they're subtly different.

```
struct S {
    S(int);
    S(const S&);
};

S s(5);   // 1
S ss = 5; // 2
```

The line marked 1 uses `S(int)` to construct `s`. The line marked 2 is a bit more complicated. Formally, it uses `S(int)` to construct a temporary object of type `S`, then uses `S(const S&)` to copy that temporary into `ss`.

However, the compiler is allowed to skip the copy, and construct `ss` directly, with `S(int)`, and in practice, every compiler does this. But the copy constructor still has to exist and be accessible; only its **use** is elided. So if `S(const S&)` was marked private, the line marked 2 would be ill-formed. You can try this out by writing a copy constructor that writes something to `std::cout` to tell you when it's called; the compiler is allowed to skip that call, even though it has visible side effects.